# The effect of x() family of functions

Tags: localization, translation

So I know that _x() and it's wrappers allow a developer to specify the context of a translated string. I'm pretty clear on "how" to use this function as well as "why" it should be used. I am wondering how this function is helpful to people who perform translations. Poedit does not seem to treat it any differently. Does use of this function aid in translation? Is there a way for translators to somehow see the context during the translation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using other translation tools (other then poedit) like **GlotPress** you can see the context in which the string for translation is called upon.

Comment: Haven't tried GlotPress yet. Maybe it's time to give it a go :) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Its something i myself just picked  up two months ago at the Israeli WordPress Translators convention.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing. I try to learn as much about i18n as possible. I have the handicap of only speaking one language and I'm pretty horrible at that actually :)

Comment: Well its better to know one language form a-z then to know 5 languages from a-g (like me).